# Manually Pass Argument Through Code (bypass command line argument)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script I'm using for python that takes command line arguments, but it only takes 1 command line argument at a time. I want to run multiple 100's of this and I can only do 1 at a time. I'm trying to manually override the command line argument that is passed through. Is there someway to write something in so I can write in what the command line argument is?

For example, the code grabs a command line argument via:

```
parser.add_argument('name', action='store', help='name')
```

In a perfect world, I want to find something where I can just say on the next line, where argument = 'name', make it "x" (where x I can say whatever I want) and I can pass it through as a module.

The reason I just don't change it is because there is an entire script written that takes into account the argument, and I'd have to go through and rewrite a lot of logic. If I could just override this 1 argument through code, I could effectively have the program run 100s of times.

I tried to do pass an OS argument to manually run the command each time, but the program seems to stall when I run an OS command.

Is this possible? I can't seem to find anything on this, so I'm worried it may not.

Comment: Why aren't you using simply using a variable as 'name' and passing an argument to it?

Comment: im assuming the code above, that "grabs" the argument as the first command line argument, but i'm not seeing anywhere i can "pass" an argument to. what do you mean by passing an argument to a variable? i want to avoid the command line entirely, i'm trying to artifically through the code force an entry as the first command line argument

Comment: To this seems like you trying to solve a problem by creating a harder problem and then getting stuck. Can we please see the original problem that you tried to solve this way? Currently the information is too vague and focused around how you tried to solve it. This way you will probably get more and better answers. It's also good to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask